# How to loop through a parsed csv with apache commons csv parser

Tags: java, apache, csv

I feel like this should be really simple but I've been trying to figure it out for what seems like forever. I have two comma delimited `String` and I'm using Apache Commons CSV `CSVParser` to parse them. I want to loop through them and put the data into a `JSONObject`.

Here is my code, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
ArrayList<String> lblList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.newFormat(',').withQuote('"');
CSVParser labels = CSVParser.parse(rf.getColumnLabels_CSV(), format);
CSVParser data = CSVParser.parse(rf.getData_CSV(), format);
JSONObject entry = new JSONObject();

for (CSVRecord label : labels) {
    lblList.add(label.get(0));
}
for (CSVRecord value : data) {
    lblList.add(value.get(0));
}

for (int i = 0; i < lblList.size(); i++) {
    entry.put(lblList.get(i), dataList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Why are you only reading the first column of your CSV data? `data` is the CSV content, `value` is one *row* from that content, and `value.get(0)` is the *first column* from that row. Don't you want the rest of the data on each row?

Comment: @Andreas  Thanks I see what going wrong now; however I'm still stuck on finding a way to actually loop through each column to get the rest of the data; the number of columns is going to vary so I can't just say `value.get(0); value.get(1); value.get(2)` etc.

Comment: @Andreas Nevermind I figured it out :) I just had to iterate through the iterator on each row so